# How do I get the name of the network that the phone is connected to?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, windows-phone-8.1

I want to get the name of the wifi network that my windows phone is connected to. I think it has something to do with `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation` but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202875(v=vs.105).aspx

Next time, do a google search (literally on the first page of results).